# Spring-xd batch job to ingest data from kafka to hdfs

Tags: spring-xd, apache-kafka

How to ingest data from kafka to hdfs using spring-xd batch job? I would like to have a batch job which is scheduled to run once in a day. How can I track offsets in kafka?

Answer (score 1):

I assume the stream setup `kafka | hdfs` doesn't help you as you want to run this as a batch job so that you can orchestrate as a batch job.

In this case, the out of the box XD batch job module that can run kafka -> hdfs isn't available yet. You can implement a custom batch job module.

In order to read the kafka messges, you would need a `ItemReader` implementation that reads Kafka messages from Kafka Broker. See similar approach in AMQPItemReader:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/item/amqp/AmqpItemReader.java

Looking at spring-integration-kafka would help here for Kafka specific implementation: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-kafka

To write the data into HDFS, XD already has `org.springframework.xd.batch.item.hadoop.HdfsTextItemWriter`.

Any of the existing XD batch job modules that write to HDFS would help you how to implement this. Feel free to open JIRA and your contributions are welcome.

Comment: Thank you. For time being i am trying to create stream kafka | hdfs, but unable to deploy. It is giving the following error:
DeploymentStatus{state=failed,error(s)=org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hadoopConfiguration': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobConf